Found string/rope in my electrical wall box
A little background, I've got some kind of smart switch with a screen and android on it, and then I realised it needs a neutral which I don't have.
So then I opened up one fake/blank box, which they left here for future upgrades I guess, has no switch, just blank plastic cover for the wall box.
Inside the box I found - a rope :-)
So now I'm trying to figure out where is the other end of that rope. As that rope was probably left there with an idea that someone can, in the future pull some cables up to his liking.
I figured they might go to my main electrical breaker box, or communication box. Opened up both cable trays that feed those cabinets from the ceiling - but no luck there.
Anyone has any creative ideas, before I start dismantling this apartment like a lunatic? :-)
Another idea I have is that they might pulled it to the next box, which is a socket, but would that even make any sense? are those even connected with the in-wall conduit?
Too bad I can't trace the rope with a cable tone tracer :-)
here is the box:



Note that local laws may not allow apartment dwellers to do electrical work themselves. You can burn down your own house, but not everyone else's apartments.

Usually you have conduit or not.  Depending on the location, it would be all conduit.  Leaving loose rope in a panel might not be allowed, so maybe the conduit ends/stops close by, to be finish if a circuit is placed in it.

@JonCuster based on the photos it appears the OP is not in the US, and laws prohibiting renters from performing electrical work may be different.  Terminology may also differ, as people may actually own what they call apartments.  (Which is why it's always helpful for people to say where they live.)

@Huesmann - indeed, hence why the comment was couched as "may" - local law and codes prevail. But, many condominiums in the US (aka owned apartments) also have similar requirements on work being done by licensed bonded (insured) professionals to give the building somebody to go after if there is a major mistake made that impacts more than the one person's apartment/condo.

Hi, correct, not usa. Middle east, uae. I own the apartment. Maintenance here is done by underpaid subcontinent "specialists". Like bicycle repairmen become universal carpenters/plumbers/electricians/drywallers/etc/etc. Jack of all trades master of none.Trust me, I'm better off handling my own maintenance then those "electricians", and thats exactly what I have been doing for the last 6 years.
